# Django finding URLs for templates

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to figure out a way to build a list of URLs for my content in my django app. I have the Models and Views setup properly, and I already figured out how to access this data in the Templates, but I'm not quite sure how I can start making URLs for them.

The data I have is continents and the countries of these continents. The template should render a list of the continents, but as links.

Here's an example with one continent:

```
<ul id="continentMenu">
  <li><a href="insert-path-to-continent-using-the-template">Scandinavia</a></li>
</ul>
```

My urls.py looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('countrydata.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('selectui.urls')),
]
```

and my index.html looks like

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}!
     <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My continentmenu.html, which I'm trying to have the links for the continents in, looks like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block content %}


    <div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="l">
                {% for continent in all_continents %}

                    <h1> {{ continent.name }}</h1>
                    <p> {{ continent.code }}</p>
                    {% for country in continent.countries.all %}
                        <p> {{country.name}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endfor %}
            </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

At the moment, but I only made it print all the continents and countries as plain text to make sure that I was successfully parsing through the objects (which I was). I'm having trouble at figuring out what kind of instructions I need to put into {% url %}, as my first attempts lead to nothing but errors.

The ajax.js I've been given to work with looks like

```
/* Run once document ready. */
$(function() {
    "use strict";
#continentMenu.
    $("#continentMenu a").on("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#continentName").text($(this).text());

        $("#tableContainer").load(url);
    });
});
```

and the views.py looks like

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from countrydata.models import Continent


def show_continent(request, continent_code=None):
    context = {
        "all_continents": Continent.objects.all()
    }
    if continent_code:
        continent = get_object_or_404(Continent, code=continent_code)
        context["continent"] = continent

    return render(request, "selectui/index.html", context)
```

Comment: ***what kind of instructions I need to put into {% url %}*** it's all about what you want to do, can you be more specific?

Comment: I'll need to write a way to change the contentWindow content into views.py, and need to figure out a way to access these views in the template using the URL. Normally show_continent displays all continents, but after clicking one of the continent links, it displays only one of them. When a continent is non-none, the table shows countries belonging to the continent instead and links to these countries (I need to create a new function into views.py for this). 

I'm not sure how I can figure out how to actually access show_continent -function from views.py using an URL in the template.

Comment: I figured it out, the correct url name I had to use was `continent-details`, so `{% for continent in all_continents %}
                        <li> <a href="{% url "continent-details" continent.code %}">{{continent.name}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}`

works for me